# How can I fix this "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me with my assignment!

My goal is that the user can choose whose grade he/she wants to see in a certain subject. The output should be something like this:

```
Name: Mary , Math Grade: 98
```

This is what I have so far:

```
N = int(input("Please enter number of students: "))

while (N < 2 or N > 10):
    N = int(input("Please only enter 2 - 10 students: "))

name = []
math_grade = []
science_grade = []

while (N != 0):
    name.append(input('Enter name:'))
    math_grade.append(input('Enter grade in math:'))
    science_grade.append(input('Enter grade in science:'))
    N = N - 1

record = []    
record.append(name)
record.append(math_grade)
record.append(science_grade)

Class_Record = {}

for name, math_grade, science_grade in record:
    Class_Record[name] = {"name": name, "math grade": math_grade, "science grade": science_grade }
```

I keep getting the value error at that point. I also don't know how to print it to get what I want.

If you can help me fix the error and tell me how I can print my desired output, I would be really grateful!!!

Comment: Note that `record` is a list of lists. Each iteration of the for loop is going to attempt to extract one of the list elements (i.e. `name`, `math_grade`, or `science_grade`) into three variables of the same names. If `name = ['alice', 'bob']`, the the first iteration of the loop will attempt to perform `name, math_grade, science_grade = ['alice', 'bob']`, which results in the unpacking error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you've organized the `record` list.

This line of code expects each item in `record` to be a sub-list with three items: name, math grade, and science grade.

```
for name, math_grade, science_grade in record
```

So it's expecting `record` to be something like this:

```
record = [
    ["Jim", "B", "C"],
    ["Mary", "A", "B"],
]
```

But instead, you made `record` to be a sub-list of names, then a sub-list of math grades, then a sub-list of science grades:

```
record = [
    ["Jim", "Mary"],
    ["B", "A"],
    ["C", "B"]
]
```

So when the code pulls the first item in `record`, it's a list of only two items, where you told it to expect three.  (If you had three students, the code would have "worked", but not the way you wanted.)

So you either have to change how you put things into `record` to match how you're pulling them out, or change how you're pulling them out.

In fact, it seems like `record` is just a temporary variable that is only used to build `Class_Record`.  If that's true, you could just build `Class_Record` directly:

```
Class_Record = {}

while (N != 0):
    name = input('Enter name:')
    math_grade = input('Enter grade in math:')
    science_grade = input('Enter grade in science:')
    Class_Record[name] = {'math_grade': math_grade, 'science_grade': science_grade)
    N = N - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input("Please enter number of students: "))

while (N < 2 or N > 10):
    N = int(input("Please only enter 2 - 10 students: "))

Class_Record = []

while (N != 0):
    name = input('Enter name:')
    math_grade = input('Enter grade in math:')
    science_grade = input('Enter grade in science:')
    temp = {'name': name, 'math grade': math_grade, 'science grade': science_grade}
    Class_Record.append (temp)
    N = N - 1

print (Class_Record)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like below

```
N = int(input("Please enter number of students: "))

while (N < 2 or N > 10):
    N = int(input("Please only enter 2 - 10 students: "))


Class_Record={}
while (N != 0):
    name = input('Enter name:')
    math_grade = input('Enter grade in math:')
    science_grade = input('Enter grade in science:')
    Class_Record[name]={"name": name, "math grade": math_grade, "science grade": science_grade}
    N = N - 1

print(Class_Record)
```